# Searching for a term using SQL MATCH which includes spaces

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This may be a newbie question, as I'm not an expert in SQL. However, couldn't find the answer using Google.
I have a table called *record_fields* which contains the majority of my system's content, which I want to search in. The *content* cell is defined as LONGTEXT as it can include extremely long input.

Originally, I used (simplifying the query a bit for clarity sake):

```
SELECT * FROM record_fields WHERE LOWER(content) LIKE LOWER('%{$keyword}%')
```

Execution time aside, this query has one major issue. If I search for the term "post" it will return all content which has words like "poster", "posting" and others. I wanted to add a FULLTEXT search.

Now the query looks like this (again, simplified):

```
SELECT * FROM record_fields WHERE MATCH (content) AGAINST ('{$keyword}')
```

However, this is still problematic. With MATCH, if my system's users search for the words "Bank of America", for example, all records that either have the word "Bank" and "America" will be returned.

**TL;DR** - my question is this:

> how do I use MATCH to search for exact phrases with space in them?

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

%{keyword}% matches all text sub-strings that include your keyword anywhere in the string. MATCH usually takes all keywords in the match string as individual search terms, and matches against each. You can use boolean mode and use a + symbol before each required keyword. Take a look at the [MySQL reference for this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

Edited the answer to reflect Idan's response in not getting the results from the suggested %keyword solution.

Comment: BOOLEAN appears to be the right answer for my problem. From the documentation: 

'"some words"'
Find rows that contain the exact phrase “some words” (for example, rows that contain “some words of wisdom” but not “some noise words”). Note that the “"” characters that enclose the phrase are operator characters that delimit the phrase. They are not the quotation marks that enclose the search string itself. Thanks!

Comment: Also adding a comment for those who are having the same issue, the suggested '%keyword' solution didn't work reliably. Some records containing the phrase were not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Match Against With Boolean Mode and you can put your input string inside '"{$keyword}"'.

Check last example in below link

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

```
SELECT * FROM record_fields WHERE MATCH (content) AGAINST ('"{$keyword}"' IN BOOLEAN MODE )
```